# The size of the subset that maximizes variance

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, combinations

I have a set $S =\{p_i\}_{i=1}^N$ data points. Each data point has dimensionality of $D$. Now for each subset $L \subset S$, I compute the sum of variance of each dimension of $L$, namely:
$
\text{var}(L) = \sum_i \sigma_i^2, i\in {1...D}
$

I figure out (by testing with code) that the subset that has the maximum variance $\text{var}(L)$ always has the size (number of data points) $\leq D+2$.

Might be my observation is wrong, but in all of my test cases, it's true. Is there a proof for that?

**UPDATED**: Here is my code for testing:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from tqdm import tqdm

# testing parameters
N = 1000  # number of runs
D = 3  # datapoint dimensionality
K = 10  # number of data points

print('Number of run: ', N)
print('Dimensionality: ', D)
print('Number of subsets in each run ', 2 ** K)


# function to calculate the spreading metric
def spreading_metric(s):
    return np.var(s, axis=0).sum()


for i in tqdm(range(N)):
    points = np.random.rand(K, D)
    size_max = 0
    v_max = -1
    for k in range(2, K + 1):
        for comb in combinations(range(points.shape[0]), k):
            rows = list(comb)
            v = spreading_metric(points[rows])
            if v > v_max:
                v_max = v
                size_max = len(rows)
    assert size_max <= D + 3, f'wrong theory caught for size_max {size_max} !!!'

print('Test passed!')
```

In fact, after sometimes testing, $D+3$ seems to be the good bound. Still, if you could provide proof or a better bound, I really appreciate it.

Here is one example for $D=2$.

```
>>> points
array([[0.22092705, 0.40871716],
       [0.29761191, 0.10001131],
       [0.92967956, 0.50780717],
       [0.0432983 , 0.28589581],
       [0.47457283, 0.44952723],
       [0.05990606, 0.91755492],
       [0.76807522, 0.96215681],
       [0.38944321, 0.226995  ],
       [0.66338676, 0.57872981],
       [0.23038586, 0.4326604 ]])
```

The best subset (var = 0.249) is:

```
array([[0.29761191, 0.10001131],
       [0.92967956, 0.50780717],
       [0.0432983 , 0.28589581],
       [0.05990606, 0.91755492],
       [0.76807522, 0.96215681]])
```

Comment: Suppose $D=1$, $N=4$, and your data points are $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Which $L$ has maximum variance?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Then L = {1,4}, which has the size = 2

Comment: @MikeEarnest: (regarding the deleted answer) Well, I was dealing with coordinates in the same way as the OP, but I was using the sample variance formula with $n-1$ in the denominator, except that I had inexplicably remembered it as $n+1$... Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: Your observation is what I would have expected. Actually I would even have guessed that it is $D+1$: among all the data points, take the vertices in a simplex of maximum volume. My inutition is that these points are somehow "maximally far apart" and adding any other point gives you relatively small sum-of-squares improvement in the numerator at the cost of an increased denominator. But if you have examples where $D+2$ are really necessary, then I would in fact guess that you can arrange things very carefully to need more. Although perhaps not *many* more; I'd believe $O(D)$ or $O(D\log D)$.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky After many runs, I can see the bound $D+2$ is not correct. Instead, $D+3$ passed all the test cases.
I provided a piece of code for testing in the updated question.

Comment: For what it's worth, I expect that the data sets that require large subsets will be hard to get via your method; in general "random" sets should be very close to $D+1$, whereas the large ones come from sets that are (approximately) "balanced" in some way (this is what I meant by 'can arrange things very carefully'). I tried to do this with the points on an octahedron; this doesn't quite work but I do expect counterexamples to be similar. So your code here doesn't do a lot to convince me $D+3$ is the correct bound, frankly.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky Thanks for the comment. Indeed, I have no ways to say D+3 is the correct bound via passing my test cases. Due to the limitation of my laptop, I couldn't test more (tried with K=15, but I stopped after 2 hours). The bound may depend on the size of the data set. My test shows that the larger the set, the lower the bound.

Comment: [Let's continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132317/room-for-eric-nathan-stucky-and-lenhhoxung)